# How to find results based on item ordering

Tags: sql, sqlite, having

Say you have a table of Items with UniqueNames, Ids to denote the order, and a RunNumber for each Run

| Id | Name | RunNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Open | 1 |
| 2 | Close | 1 |
| 1 | Open | 2 |
| 2 | Close | 2 |
| 1 | Close | 3 |
| 2 | Open | 3 |
| 1 | Open | 4 |
| 2 | Close | 4 |

Is there a way to get the RunNumbers where the item order has changed,
eg where "Id of 'Close' Task is **less** than Id of 'Open' Task" (like RunNumber 3) ?

Hoping to learn of a few methods, but one will suffice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT RunNumber
FROM Items
GROUP BY RunNumber
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Close' THEN Id END) < MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Open' THEN Id END);
```

Or, with a self join:

```
SELECT i1.RunNumber
FROM Items i1 INNER JOIN Items i2
ON i1.RunNumber = i2.RunNumber AND i1.id < i2.id
WHERE i1.Name = 'Close' AND i2.Name = 'Open';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GY1DDrwL).

Answer (score 0):

Since `Close` alphabitically is before `Open`, then you can use `row_number()` to give row number to each record grouped by RunNumber and ordered by Name :

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by RunNumber order by id, Name) as rn
  from mytable
)
select *
from cte
where id = 1 and rn = 1 and Name = 'Close';
```

Or You can specify the order of `Close` and `Open` yourself using `order by` `case when` :

```
with cte as (
  select *,
  row_number() over (partition by RunNumber order by case Name when 'Close' then 1 when 'Open' then 2 end, id) as rn
  from mytable
)
select *
from cte
where id = 1 and rn = 1 and Name = 'Close';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DTINB3Ea)